# How would I update a controller variable that is outside of a $scope.$on from within it in angular?

Tags: angularjs, scope, watch

I have a variable in my angular controller and I have a $scope.$on that I want to update that variable when it is called. However, I can't seem to figure out how to update that variable from within the $scope.$on. When I try to console.log the changed variable from within and from outside, it doesn't get updated. Any ideas on how to accomplish what I need?

```
ctrl.updateThisVar = false;

$scope.$on('app::createNew', function($event, args) {
  ctrl.updateThisVar = true;
  // also tried scope.controllerName.updateThisVar = true;
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the variable?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$scope.$on('app::createNew', function($event, args) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
        ctrl.updateThisVar = true;
  })
  // also tried scope.controllerName.updateThisVar = true;
});
```